# Scrollview only detect scrolling from certain areas?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I want to have a scrollview that covers the entire screen. However I want to know if it is possible to only allow scrolling to be detected from part of the scrollview. For example you have a full screen scroll view the top half of the screen should detect scrolling but the bottom half should not. I know if you change the alpha to 0 the scrollview doesn't scroll anymore, would a possible solution be to change the alpha of part of the scrollview? is that even possible? any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: A simple solution is to add the table view to ViewController and add clear view over the part of the table view that you don't want to allow touches at

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass from UIScrollView and override method `touchesShouldBegin`.
You should check at what point touches and allow it or not.

```
class ScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func touchesShouldBegin(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?, in view: UIView) -> Bool {

        if (touches.first?.location(in: self).y)! > self.bounds.height / 2 {
            // In bottom part
            return true
        }

        // In top part
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i have so far func touchesShouldBegin(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, 
                   with event: UIEvent?, 
                     in view: UIView) -> Bool { } how would i write the if statement to check where the touch points are